# Is it possible to bake all simulations before rendering automatically?

Tags: rendering, baking

I am currently learning blender, and I am trying to bake simulations in render as I plan to use a cloud render to render my animation. The problem is, I don't believe I could be able to "bake simulations" in the cloud as I am using command lines to render the file.

**(Notice buttons (Simulation Baked/ Free All Bakes) this is what I need to press before rendering)**

[image]

So how is it possible for me to do this, before rendering? is there a checkbox I could click where It bakes everything first, then renders?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As far as I know, when you bake, you ended up with a cache folder containing all the baked information, if you already have the folder, you should be able to render and blender is going to use the baked information from that folder. But I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @Emir Yes, I am aware of that but to get that file you would need to bake locally, I would like to bake it in the cloud, not bake it in my local machine as it would take too much time unfortunately